# Core Data Managed Object one-to-many relationship insert/update save

Tags: core-data, insert, save, one-to-many, relationship

Lets assume I have person->phones relationship (One to many of course). Initial insert save is working correctly where I do:

```
    if (does not exist) {
      user = (Member *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
} else {
    searchObjectsForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:pred andSortKey:nil andSortAscending:NO andContext:ctx];
```

Should this be replaced with just one insertNewObjectForEntityForName which would either insert or get existing?

Next, I need to create my phones objects and add them to my Person which I do with something like this:

```
NSManagedObject* mo=nil;
Phone* phone = (Phone *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Phone"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
[mutableSetOfPhones addObject:mo];
user.phones = phones;
```

So I create a new instance of phone managed object add it to a set and add it to person, after that I save. 
All this is good except when I use the same code to re-save Person instance i.e. edit/insert/delete a phone or any other modifications to user data. Old records of phones remain in the DB and are no longer associated with any Person.

What is the right approach of doing this? Do I need to iterate through user.phones to see edits/deletes by some id? Should I just delete older instances prior to saving updated records (much simpler)? What is the recommended approach, maybe I am doing something completely incorrect?

Comment: In your second block of code, you create `phone`, but then you add `mo` (which is nil) to `mutableSetOfPhones` - did you mean to add `phone` instead? You then set `user.phones` to `phones`, which doesn't appear previously in your code - did you mean to set it to `mutableSetOfPhones` instead? In either case, you seem to be managing the set of phones yourself, then handing the entire set to the managed object. Why not let the managed object handle the set (which it already has methods for) and you just add/delete phones individually as they come in? That will avoid orphaning old phones.

Comment: thanks for response.. mo is a managed object of phone, it was a copy paste from multiple places. Multiple objects, in this example phones, are edited separately and only when user profile is being saved collected together to the modified user profile. Basically instead of using Managed Objects, wrapper objects are used until save time, at which point I call myPhone->getMePhoneMO which is supposed to return Phone Managed object.
I am not editing managed objects directly within Person managed object.

Comment: Alternative I think would be to use user object and go through each managed object (phone) and try to sync with modified data which is exactly what I am asking.  This seems more complicated and slower than just deleting old data and replace it with new?

Comment: As of right now deleting user object prior to re save deletes all relationships. Not sure if it is the best way but works for now.
so I delete and then insert a new user object follow with the regular save.